# Proof that a real valued function f in an interval [a,b], is Riemann integrable in this interval?

Tags: integration, analysis, functions

so we know that a convex function in [a,b], is continuous in (a,b), so the only problem that we might be having is in point a and/or In point b.

I would really appreciate some help in how can I do it. I don't think I can do it by proving differentiability in these to points, and then I thought I can do it by proving monotony in these two points but I also didn't get anywhere with that.

So I would really be open and grateful for some suggestions.

Ps. My previous question got closed because I didn't give much details so I hope this is better. And I know these things might seem common sense or 'very easy' to some people here, but I think that a bit of solidarity and help in the community would be very beneficial for all of us and the main purpose should actually be spreading knowledge, instead of just closing people questions and being rude.

Comment: Somewhat depends on what we mean by a convex function in $[a,b]$. Would you say $f(x)=1/x$ is convex on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Riemann integration doesn't play well with infinite values :-).

Comment: @copper.hat Yes so OP might want to clarify the question with "$f$ is real-valued on $[a,b]$"

Comment: @bjorn93 yes indeed, I included it now in the question

Answer (score 0):

A bounded function on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable **iff** the set of discontinuities has measure zero. Since the only possible discontinuities are at $a,b$ we see that the discontinuity condition is satisfied.

It remains to show that $f$ is bounded.

Assuming the function is real valued, then $f(a),f(b)$ are finite and $f(x) \le \max(f(a),f(b))$ for all $x$.

Pick two distinct points $u<v$ in $(a,b)$. And let $l$ be the line passing
through the points $(u,f(u)), (v,f(v))$.

Since $f$ is convex, we have
$f(tu+(1-t)v) \ge l(tu+(1-t)v)$ for all $t \notin (0,1)$.

Since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on $[u,v]$ hence $f$ is bounded everywhere.